# How can I allow users to reset their Linux user passwords from a web interface?

Tags: linux, centos, passwd, useradd

I am running SAS Visual Analytics on a cluster for my department. I want the users to be able to set and reset their own password for their user account. Users and Passwords for the application are based on the local users and passwords on the server.

Is there any tool that already exists that allows a user to change their local password from a web interface?

Comment: Looks like webmin allows you to [do exactly that](http://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Change_Passwords)

Comment: There are numerous solutions around, have a read of: [Script to change password on linux servers over ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236699/script-to-change-password-on-linux-servers-over-ssh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you could write your own.  The password in `/etc/shadow` is generally just a hash, the type of which can be defined in your `/etc/pam.d/`  configuration.

Hash a new password, stick it in /etc/shadow, and you've just changed the user's password.

Much much more information on the hashing/encryption of passwords and how to programmatically modify them can be found in `man 3 crypt`